# Composing two functions with different exception types (java generics)

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

Let's say I want to implement a version of `java.util.function.Function<T,R>` that can throw some exception type `E`. What I have done is create a functional interface named `ThrowingFunction` like so :

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception>
{
    R apply(T t) throws E;
}
```

Now like in the `java.util.function.Function<T,R>`, I need to implement the default method `compose` and what I need is to compose two different `ThrowingFunction` instances **and likely, they can have a different throwing exception type**. So here is my try :

```
default <V, E1 extends Exception, E2 super E1 & E> ThrowingFunction<V, R, E2> compose(ThrowingFunction<? super V, ? extends T, ? extends E1> before)
{
    return v -> apply(before.apply(v));
}
```

Here of course, I get a compiler error saying :

> Syntax error on token "super", extends expected

Exactly in the declaration of the generic parameter `E2 super E1 & E`.

So, what is the possible solutions of this problem, do I just compose two different `ThrowingFunction` instances having the same exception type `E` (*and this is not what is preferably wanted*) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `default` method here; it must be a `static` method on the interface.  When you attempt to use a `default` method, the type `E` has been captured already, and the Java compiler will not allow you to declare the type `E2` to be a supertype of anything much less 2 types `E` and `E1`, as your compiler error indicates.

When changing to a `static` method, you are free to declare your exception type parameters as you desire.  You can declare a supertype exception type `S`, followed by subtype exception types `E1` and `E2`.  Then the rest follows similarly to `Function`'s default `compose` method.

The type parameters here match what `Function.compose` uses, with the addition of the exception-related type parameters.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception>
{
    R apply(T t) throws E;

    /**
     * Composes f (after) and g (before) to produce the composed
     * function f o g(v), which executes f(g(v)).
     * @param f The function that will take g's output <T> as input to return the overall result <R>.
     * @param g The function that will take the overall input <V> and return f's input <T>.
     * @param <V> The input result type of the entire composed function (and of function g).
     * @param <T> The result type of g, used as input to f.
     * @param <R> The end result type of the entire composed function (and of function f).
     * @param <S> If any of f or g throws an exception, it is captured by the supertype exception class S.
     * @param <E1> The exception type thrown by f.
     * @param <E2> The exception type thrown by g.
     * @return A ThrowingFunction that whose input <V> is applied to g, whose result is passed to
     *     f to generate the overall result <R>.
     */
    static <V, T, R, S extends Exception, E1 extends S, E2 extends S> ThrowingFunction<V, R, S>
        compose(ThrowingFunction<? super T, ? extends R, ? extends E1> f,
                ThrowingFunction<? super V, ? extends T, ? extends E2> g)
    {
        return v -> f.apply(g.apply(v));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, this is indeed the only solution that is left to consider. What do you think about migrating to java9 and implement the static `compose` method as private and let the public default `compose` method call the static one. Because in my api design the user is restricted to compose two `ThrowingFunction` instances only in this way `f1.compose(f2)`.